# possible to output return value on 1 line in PHP?

Tags: php, function, return-value

Say I have this function in PHP

```
<?php
function get_filename_parts($fname){
/*
receives a filename and returns an array with the filename & extension
example:
receives:   myfile1.jpg
returns:    array('filename' => 'myfile1', 'extension' => 'jpg')

receives:   myfile1.blah.blah.jpg
returns:    array('filename' => 'myfile1.blah.blah', 'extension' => 'jpg')

*/
$name_no_ext = explode('.',$fname);
$ext = array_pop($name_no_ext);
$name_no_ext = implode('.',$name_no_ext);

$retval = array('filename' => $name_no_ext, 'extension' => $ext);

return $retval;
}
?>
```

Is there some syntax to do something like this in a single statement:

```
 <?php echo get_filename_parts('test.txt')->filename; ?>
```

instead of:

```
 <?php $fname = get_filename_parts('test.txt'); echo $fname['filename']; ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing it on one line either way... but you mean "in a single statement" right?

Comment: You need php 5.4 to do that, otherwise your second example would have to suffice.

Comment: I meant in a single statement. Editing the OP to clarify.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the helpful replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.4, you can do the shorthand:

`$fname = get_filename_parts('test.txt')['filename'];`

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. We're stuck with 5.3.3 for now. Time to upgrade. :)

Answer (score 1):

From php version 5.4 you can use

```
$fname = get_filename_parts('test.txt')['filename'];
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP < 5.4 you can write this function:

```
function array_var($from, $name, $default = null) {
    if(is_array($from)) {
      return array_key_exists($name, $from) ? $from[$name] : $default;
    } 

    return $default;
}
```

Then you can just write

```
array_var(get_filename_parts('test.txt'), 'filename');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in PHP < 5.4, then you can use StdClass to mock your results:

example:

```
function func() {
  $results = new StdClass;

  $results->filename = 'file_name';
  $results->extension = 'extension';

  return $results;
}

echo func()->filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function get_filename_parts($fname){
    $parts = explode('.', $fname);
    $obj = new StdClass;
    $obj->extension = array_pop($parts);
    $obj->filename = implode('.', $parts);
    return $obj;
}
```

and now you can use it the way you wanted:

```
<?php echo get_filename_parts('test.txt')->filename; ?>
<?php echo get_filename_parts('test.txt')->extension; ?>
```